# jQuery passing a function call through to another function and order of execution

Tags: jquery, delayed-execution

I have this javascript:

```
triggerAnimation(listItem,toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem));


function triggerAnimation(listItem,passThruFunction){
    listItem.find(".inlineLoading").show();
// pause and then call the toggle function
    $("body").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, 
    function(){
        alert("a");
    passThruFunction;
    }
    );  
}

function toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem) {
    alert("b");
};
```

What is supposed to happen:

- triggerAnimation is called passing an object and a function
- triggerAnimation does a dummy animation (to create a pause) then raises an alert and triggers a callback function which executes the function that was passed through.
- the function that was passed through is called raising an alert.

Based on the above, I'd expect the alert A to appear before alert B but that is not the case. What happens is that (it seems) alert B is called as soon as triggerAnimation() is called. Why is that? How can I achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delay the execution by passing in a function and calling it later.

```
triggerAnimation(listItem, function () {
   toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem)
});


function triggerAnimation(listItem,passThruFunction){
    listItem.find(".inlineLoading").show();
// pause and then call the toggle function
    $("body").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, 
    function(){
        alert("a");
        passThruFunction();
    }
    );  
}

function toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem) {
    alert("b");
};
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, I admit.

Comment: that was exactly my intention! Thanks! It was a syntax error on my part by not passing it as a function in the first call (as Cesar states, it appears I was calling it, rather than passing it)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could pass the function reference and an array of parameters to trigger animation instead, which is then passed to passThruFunction on execution.
In Javascript, what you pass to a function will always be evaluated before the function code is actually executed, thats why you get your alert("b") first. 
Thats called busy evaluation [of function parameters], btw.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call the `toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem)` when you call `triggerAnimation(listItem,toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem));`, then executes `toggleToggleRadioListItem(listItem)` first.

Answer (score 1):

[eduffy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726183/jquery-passing-a-function-call-through-to-another-function-and-order-of-execution/1726205#1726205) answer is the simplest possible thing that could work, and will work a treat. If you want something more hardcore, a quiet read of [partial application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/) might give you another technique to add to your toolbelt.